# swift async code execution is stopped before it ended

Tags: swift, asynchronous

i am trying to execute a piece of code at a certain date. I can't use NSTimer as the purpose of this code si to be used in a Perfect script.`

```
import Foundation



let timeInterval: TimeInterval = 10


let future = Date().addingTimeInterval(timeInterval)

print("start")
    while true {
        if Date() > future {
            print("stop")
            break
        }
}
```

the problem is that the program is ended before it had time to print "stop". Also when i try to print something inside the loop, it is printed a few time before the program ends. Any idea on how to do that?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while true`idea is very bad, you should use **Grand Central Dispatch** instead

```
print("start")
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
    print("stop")
}
```